# star (*) issue while merging two SPSS (.sav) data file in R

Tags: r

While merging two .sav (SPSS) file in R ("version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)"), there is a star (*) appearing in exported file for those numerical variable which doesn't have any value labels in .sav (SPSS) file.All variables may or may not same in both the data file. Below is the R merging code(multi-merging) that I am using

```
list_data <- list(Data1, Data2)
mymerged_data <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), list_data)

foreign:::writeForeignSPSS(mymerged_data, "C:/mydata/data.txt", "C:/mydata/data.sps", varnames=names(mymerged_data ))
```

Below is the exported .sps file

```
DATA LIST FILE="C:/mydata/data.txt” free (",")

ENCODING="Locale"

/ SERIAL * AGE (F8.0) GENDER (F8.0) JOB (F8.0). 
...
```

You can see after "SERIAL" variable there is '*'. How to get rid of this '*' issue. In last previous R version (3.2) I didn't get any problem.